# Example of an pseudometric which is not an metric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, riemann-integration

In our lecture notes we had an example of an Pseudo-metric which is not an metric:

Let $R([a,b])$ the space of the Riemann-integrable functions on the interval $[a,b]$, where $a<b$, then
$$
\rho(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b} |f(t)-g(t)|dt
$$
is an Pseudo-metric, however no metric.
Obviously it has to fail at the condition where:
$$
\rho(f,g)=0 \implies f=g 
$$
Unfortunately, I can not find an counter-example to show this.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Take for example $f=g$ everywhere except a single point.

Comment: Just have$f,g$ differ at a single point. Riemann integrable is not the same as continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$(\scr{R}[a, b],\rho)$ is a pseudometric space. Where,
$\rho(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b} |f(t)-g(t)|dt$

It satisfies all properties of a metric except the definiteness property.i.e $\rho(f, g) =0 \iff f=g$

It satisfy only "if" part. i.e $\rho(f, g) =0 $ if $f=g$

But, $\rho(f, g) =0$ may not imply $f=g$.

For an example, $f:[a, b]\to \Bbb{R} $ where

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } x\in [a, b)\\1 &\text{ if } x=b\end{cases}$

Clearly, $f\in \scr{R}[a, b]$ as $D_f=\{b\}$

And $\rho(f, 0) =0$ but $f\not\equiv 0$.

But , $C[a, b]$ as subspace of $(\scr{R}[a, b],\rho)$ is a metric space (Check!)

Here continuity plays a crucial role to make the pseodometric to a metric.